# Can a web application detect browser proxy settings?

Tags: browser, proxy, web

Can a website or web application detect whether or not proxy settings have been specified in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

They can if the proxy inserts some standard HTTP headers that were created for this purpose. For example [x-forwarded-for](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For)

Some proxies are intended to be transparent and might not insert such headers.

Comment: yes, in that case the proxy is announcing itself.  But my question was specifically regarding the browser proxy settings; and whether they can be read somehow.